# Cant setId for a view programatically with AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android, view, android-studio

I want to add view programatically to my parent view, my view is a `RadioButton`. I also want to set an Id for the view that I add in `RadioGroup`. But when I do this it gives me an error in: mRadioButton.setId(321);

[image]

```
Reports two types of problems:
Supplying the wrong type of resource identifier. For example, when calling Resources.getString(int id), you should be passing R.string.something, not R.drawable.something.
Passing the wrong constant to a method which expects one of a specific set of constants. For example, when calling View#setLayoutDirection, the parameter must be android.view.View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR or android.view.View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL.
```

I dont know why it gives me this error.

I found that one solution would be to create `MyRadioButton` class which `extends` `RadioButton` and there I could add a variable `int MYID;` and then add `getters` and `setters` for this view.

But this is a workaround, does anyone know the solution of this problem ?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
Another workaround is to use `setTag()`
(I have used it for a horizontal view with `ImageView`'s added dynamically and it helps me to detect which one was clicked)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**If you are only supporting API 17 and higher,**

you can call [View.generateViewId](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#generateViewId())

```
ImageButton mImageButton = new ImageButton(this);
mImageButton.setId(View.generateViewId());
```

**Otherwise for apis lower than 17,**

1. open your project's `res/values/` folder
2. create an xml file called `ids.xml`

with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="imageButtonId1" type="id" />
</resources>
```

then in your code,

```
ImageButton mImageButton = new ImageButton(this);
mImageButton.setId(R.id.imageButtonId1);
```

Comment: I will mark your answer as correct but you should now that the solution that I have given is universal for all cases but a workaround unfortanetly, and for my problem I realized that I don't need to set Id :) for the moment :D